# Change Sharepoint main page name without changing URL

Tags: sharepoint, title

I have a SharePoint website, my main page is on mySiteRoot/Pages/default.aspx (quite normal until here I think) but the problem is that the name in the browser tab is also "default".

I want to change the name displaying in the tab without changing the name of the .aspx file, but despite all my searches I can't find it on SharePoint.

Does someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 5):

Each page in SharePoint should have a Name and a Title. The Name refers to the filename of the page, and thus affects the page's URL (in your case, "default.aspx").

The Title is independent of the page Name, and this is what is displayed in the browser title bar / tab.

To edit an existing page, the easiest thing to do is to navigate to `Site Actions` > `View All Site Content`. Under the "Document Libraries" area, locate and open the "Pages" library. In the library, find "default" and from either its context menu or the ribbon, select "Edit Properties". There you can change the Title to whatever you want.

Comment: I know this is old post but still useful.  Our company name changed and thus our intranet home page name needed to be renamed too.  I wasn't sure what the ramifications of making the change on our SharePoint 2007 site.  We needed to do this prior to upgrading to SharePoint 2010 and/or 2013 and beyond in our pre-cleanup efforts.  @nico I think this should be marked as the answer and maybe it wasn't because it didn't apply to the version of SharePoint you omitted and were inquiring about?

Answer (score 2):

open the page in SharePoint designer.. and look for the string:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
     <SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="BaseName" maxlength="40" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Simply replace it as:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    Your title 
</asp:Content>
```

Hopefully you will get it working.

Comment: Muhammad Murad Haide...no go. When you make the changes using designer, revisiting the page produces a "Sorry, something went wrong" and Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.

Answer (score 0):

which edition/version of SharePoint ? I guess it's 2010 with wiki home feature enabled.

If I'm right, you have to rename the file to rename the page. But don't worry, your page will still be the home page of your site.

You can in all case click on `set as default page` on any page in the ribbon.

PS: you should consider posting on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com which is the dedicated site for SharePoint Q/A.